# integration of differences of two inverse functions of CDF

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

When F, G are both cumulative distribution functions,

$\int_0^1 | F^{-1}(y) - G^{-1}(y)|dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |F(x) - G(x)|dx.$

The paper (Vallender 74') says that "The equation follows from obvious geometric considerations." and I see the point. But, is there any analytical proof/theorem that shows this?

Comment: My hunch would be to rewrite the RHS as $\int_A F  - G dx - \int_B F-G dx$ where $A$ is the set where $F \geq G$, and $B=A^c$.Then on each of the four summands I would attempt to use the integration by parts formula for Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals, before combining the integrals back into the  LHS.

Comment: I understand that I can use integration by parts on RHS, but I am not sure how to rewrite LHS so that they are equal to RHS.